# End SSH session when closing tmux session

Tags: ssh, zsh, tmux, zshrc

I have added the following to my `.zshrc` so that tmux will either create a new or attach to an existing session when logging in through SSH:

```
if [[ -z $TMUX && -n $SSH_TTY ]]; then
  me=$(whoami)

  if tmux has-session -t $me 2>/dev/null; then
    tmux -2 attach-session -t $me
  else
    tmux -2 new-session -s $me
  fi
fi
```

This seems to work. However, if I exit my tmux session, I am sent back into zsh.

Can I have it so that `exit` in the tmux session will also end the SSH session? Even better: Could `exit` in tmux just detach the tmux session, then end the SSH session?

I'm thinking that maybe a zsh alias, defined when `[[ -n $TMUX ]]`, would do the trick, but I'm not sure what would work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exec` when running tmux. It will give full control to the job you are starting, once that process exits (be it `tmux`, `echo` or `ls`) the shell will exit.

From `man zshbuiltins` *exec ... Replace the current shell with an external command rather than forking.*

```
if [[ -z $TMUX && -n $SSH_TTY ]]; then
  me=$(whoami)

  if tmux has-session -t $me 2>/dev/null; then
     exec tmux -2 attach-session -t $me
  else
     exec tmux -2 new-session -s $me
  fi
fi
```

the other alternative is to place a shell-script that starts or joins tmux, and ask `ssh` to run that instead of your shell.

```
 `alias tmux-ssh="ssh user@target-host -t /home/foo/my-tmux-script`
```

(the script must obviously be located at your remote host)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :) Went for `exec` to make it remote client agnostic, insofar as I don't have to remember to do the remote command.